# Computer Configuration does not apply after creating a new Windows image

Tags: group-policy, imaging, sysprep

I am going through the process of making a new Windows 10 Pro image for imaging our workstations. The sysprep process goes fine, but after installing the image on our devices it will not pull the Computer Configuration from Group Policy. It does pull the User Configuration however. GPUPDATE runs with out issue, but it still doesn't pull the Computer Config. When I check Group policy as an admin on the machine it does show the Computer config, but it still never shows up for the user. Any ideas on what I could be missing?